# How do I merge 2 cells in Excel using Delphi 10 (Seattle)

Tags: excel, delphi

I'm using late binding with olevariants. I have `column a` and `column b`. I want to merge `column a` and `column b` on one row. Then I want to fill and center that text in the merged a-b cell. Lastly, I want to fill the background with sky blue.

My Delphi code is as follows. I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong. I get my text and sky blue color in column a and the columns are not merged. `Colqty` should be `column a` and `colitemdescr` should be `column b`.

```
var   ExcelObj          : OLEVariant;
      startcell, endcell: olevariant; 
begin
       startcell:= ExcelObj.ActiveSheet.Cells[Row, colQty];
       endcell:= ExcelObj.ActiveSheet.Cells[Row, colItemDescr];
       startcell.Merge(endcell);
       startcell.Value := 'this is an item description';
       startcell.HorizontalAlignment := xlCenter;;
       startcell.Font.Bold := true;
       startcell.Interior.Color := clSkyBlue;
end;
```

Thanks for any help you can give me! I know Delphi has fallen out of favor but there are still a few of us around! :)

Comment: what version of Delphi are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In order for **Merge** to work you need to set a range of cells that you need merged.

In the code below, I've added a new **OLEVariant** variable named **MegredRange**. I'm using it to get the needed range of the start and end cells and then I merge them together.

```
var
  ExcelObj, StartCell, EndCell, MergedRange: OLEVariant;
begin application

  StartCell := ExcelObj.ActiveSheet.Cells[Row, ColQty];
  EndCell := ExcelObj.ActiveSheet.Cells[Row, ColItemDescr];
  MergedRange := ExcelObj.ActiveSheet.Range[StartCell, EndCell];
  MergedRange.Merge();
  MergedRange.Value := 'this is an item description';
  MergedRange.HorizontalAlignment := xlCenter;
  MergedRange.Font.Bold := true;
  MergedRange.Interior.Color := clSkyBlue;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've tried using vba excel documentation, and it has different properties, so I got a bunch of compiler errors.  I was starting to lose hope that I'd find a way to do this.  :)

Comment: @Debbie if it worked, you can accept my answer, so other people know to do this if they occur the same problem